# Перечисление диапазона между двумя столбцами

Tags: sql

Есть таблица, в которую записывается диапазон значений, начальное и конечное, в следующем формате:

| start_value | end_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 8 | 10 |

Каким запросом можно преобразовать в следующий вывод, т.е. перечисление всех значений от и до по каждой строке?

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |

Comment: Обычный рекурсивный CTE...